# Однотипные операции с большим объемом фото

Tags: photo

К сожалению, не нашел такого функционала в paint.net, может кто-нибудь подскажет какой-то **свободный** софт для преобразования группы фотографий: нужно уменьшить их размер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faststone Imageviewer - очень рекомендую. Включаете пакетное преобразование (F3) - и понеслась).

Comment: Очень хороший совет, огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

В php были подобные функции. Можно построить список директории и проделать нужные изменения со всем списком.

Comment: Ага, можно и на C# написать её. Только я думаю, что без меня уже всё написано.

Хотя сейчас у меня более серьезная проблема:

http://www.facebook.com/notes/tim-rudnevsky/ps-vs-cmd-vs-cygwin/216179478409719

Answer (score 0):

Если ОС Windows, то в Microsoft Picture Manager можно делать однотипные множественные операции

Answer (score 0):

Есть любимый веб-программерами (по крайней мере ранее) Imagemagic, есть gimp с парамером -b/--batch=commands. Проще в данном случае использовать Imagemagic

Comment: Только называется он ImageMagick (игра слов).